# Cannot serialize member * because it is an interface

Tags: c#, asp.net

Pessoal esbarrei no erro acima ao tentar criar um `webservice` e estou tendo dificuldade para interpretá-lo e tratá-lo.

**Detalhando o que eu fiz:**

Dentro de um projeto `InpartSaude.WebApi.Api` em uma de minhas `controllers` possuo um método para obter dados de um usuário, ao acessar pelo navegador:

```
http://localhost:24083/InpartSaudeApi/Usuario/ObterUsuario?login=kk&senha=kkk
```

Consegui retornar um `XML` com os dados como esperado.

Em seguida no mesmo projeto criei um `WebService` "WebServiceUsuario.asmx", copiei o método da controller para esse `[WebMethod]` e tentei executá-lo a fim de testar meu `webservice` mas me deparei com o erro do título. Estou aprendendo meio que na prática e não consegui compreender o erro e nem uma forma corrigi-lo.

Segue abaixo o método:

```
 public class WebServiceUsuario : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public List<Data.Usuario> ObterUsuario(string login, string senha)
        {
            using (InpartSaudeEntities db = new InpartSaudeEntities()) {

                return (from x in db.Usuario
                             from y in db.UsuarioDistribuidor.Where(a => a.idUsuario == x.idUsuario).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             from z in db.Distribuidor.Where(b => b.idDistribuidor == y.idDistribuidor).DefaultIfEmpty()
                             where x.nmLogin == login
                                  && x.nmSenha == senha
                                  && x.blAtivo == 1
                                  && x.blBloqueado == false
                             select x
                       ).ToList().Select(x => new Usuario {
                           idUsuario = x.idUsuario,
                           cdTipoUsuario = x.cdTipoUsuario,
                           idGrupoCliente = x.idGrupoCliente,
                           idPerfil = x.idPerfil,
                           nmEmail = x.nmEmail,
                           nmLogin = x.nmLogin,
                           nmUsuario = x.nmUsuario,
                           idDistribuidor = x.idDistribuidor
                       }
                    ).ToList();


            }
        }
    }
```

Minha classe `Data.Usuario` vem do `edmx`, ou seja, ela foi gerada automaticamente pelo `EF`.

Comment: Poste a definição de `Data.Usuario`, por favor.

Comment: Tenta tacar um `[Serializable]` na classe.

Comment: Ainda não conseguiu resolver?

Comment: Estou pesquisando aqui para ver o que pode ser, tentei o Serializable mas ele fala que não é possível usar com esse tipo de dado, talvez eu deva retornar em outro formato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do problema o `WebMethod` não é capaz de serializar uma interface, ou seja, ele não é capaz de serializar a classe vinda direto do `Entity`.

Para corrigir o problema eu criei uma classe `UsuarioWebMethod` que servirá como intermediária, assim o `WebMethod` retornará uma instância dessa classe com os dados do banco.

```
public class UsuarioWebMethod {
  public int? Id { get; set; }
  public String Nome { get; set; }
  public int? IdPerfil { get; set; }
  public String Login { get; set; }
  public String Email { get; set; }
  public String Senha { get; set; }
  public String TipoUsuario { get; set; }
  public int? IdGrupoCliente { get; set; }
  public int? IdDistribuidor { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public List<UsuarioWebMethod> ObterUsuario(string login, string senha)
{
   using (InpartSaudeEntities db = new InpartSaudeEntities()) {
   var usuarios = (from x in db.Usuario
       from y in db.UsuarioDistribuidor.Where(a => a.idUsuario == x.idUsuario).DefaultIfEmpty()
       from z in db.Distribuidor.Where(b => b.idDistribuidor == y.idDistribuidor).DefaultIfEmpty()
       where x.nmLogin == login
         && x.nmSenha == senha
         && x.blAtivo == 1
         && x.blBloqueado == false
       select x
       ).ToList().Select(x => new UsuarioWebMethod {
         Id = x.idUsuario,
         TipoUsuario = x.cdTipoUsuario,
         IdGrupoCliente = x.idGrupoCliente,
         IdPerfil = x.idPerfil,
         Email = x.nmEmail,
         Login = x.nmLogin,
         Nome = x.nmUsuario,
         IdDistribuidor = x.idDistribuidor
      }).ToList();

    return usuarios;
  }
}
```